Programmatically bring notebook to front, open minimized notebooks? (particularly to Messages)
I want to do the equivalent of navigating to the Window menu and selecting a notebook. In particular, I'm interested in forcing the messages window to the front. My reason for that is that the Messages are not obvious enough.
Related: Open Notebook Minimized to TaskBar


I found the token I needed:
FrontEndTokenExecute[MessagesNotebook[], "SelectNotebookWindow"]

What is the complete list of valid Front End Tokens?
